# Is it true that every invariant on manifolds comes from cohomology groups?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

> **Question:** Is it true that every invariant on manifolds comes from Homological groups?

For example, characteristics classes, Betti numbers, fundamental groups (By Hurewicz's theorem), Signature of 4d-manifolds (defined by middle **co**homology group), Intersection forms (defined by middle **co**homology group), etc. I think all of these are related somehow to (**co**)homology groups. If so why geometers trying to find new invariants?

Comment: The fundamental group doesn't come from homology...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not true at all. For example, there is an infinite number of diffeomorphism classes of manifolds with the same homology groups as $S^3$.

Besides, your examples are wrong.

- Characteristic classes are elements of **co**homology groups. Moreover, you cannot deduce what the characteristic classes are just by knowing the homology groups. They are extra information.
- You cannot know the fundamental group of a manifold if you just know its homology groups. Yes, if $M$ is path-connected, then Hurewicz's theorem says that $H_1(M)$ is the abelianization of $M$. But 1. if $M$ is not path-connected then extracting information about the different $\pi_1(M)$ from $H_1(M)$ is difficult, because you don't know what comes from which component; 2. knowing the abelianization of a group is not enough to know the group, as e.g. there are nontrivial groups with trivial abelianization (called perfect groups).

Other invariants that are not captured by the homology groups alone include the cup product on cohomology, the signature for $4d$-manifolds, the higher homotopy groups and their Whitehead product, etc. In all cases you can cook up examples with the same homology groups but where the invariants mentioned differ.

Comment: Can we deduce what the characteristic classes are just by knowing the cohomology groups? I know it is not appropriate to ask another question or change that, but what  really the characteristic classes measure that cohomology (or homotopy) groups can't?

Comment: @C.F.G No, you can't deduce the characteristic classes just by knowing the cohomology groups (unless the cohomology group involved is $0$, obviously). They measure whatever they measure, it depends on the precise class you're looking at. For example the Euler class can tell you about non-vanishing vector fields. The Chern classes can give info about how many linearly independent vector fields you can find. Pontryagin classes are related to the curvature. There's no general answer.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Could you help me with this please? where we are using that $f,g:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$ are homotopic in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104795/homotopic-maps-x-a-to-y-b-induce-homotopic-maps-x-a-to-x-b.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: (too late) Actually [Signature for 4d-manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)) and  [Intersection form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory) are made by (middle) **co**homology groups.

Comment: @C.F.G Sorry, I don't get your point. Yes, signature is a quadratic form on the middle cohomology group. But you cannot deduce what the signature is just from knowing the cohomology groups. If I told you a space $X$ was a $4$ manifold with $H^{2}(X) = \mathbb{R}^2$, would you be able to tell me what the signature was? No, because $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# \overline{\mathbb{CP}}^2$ are two such manifolds with different signature.